# Properties of adjoints of linear maps

Tags: linear-algebra

I am studying linear algebra by myself, and I came across the need to prove the following, for adjoints of linear maps:

($f^\dagger)^\dagger=f$

$(f\circ g)^\dagger=g^\dagger\circ f^\dagger$

$\langle v|fw\rangle=\langle f^\dagger v|w\rangle$

Thank you very much!

Comment: Do you know the definition of the adjoint? I strongly recommend that you do these yourself, because they're very easy. If you still can't do them, tell us what you have tried.

Comment: Thank you. Off course, the first 2 are obvious if I accept the third. But if I don't, I don't know where to start.

Comment: The third is usually the *definition* of the adjoint. What is your definition?

Answer (score 1):

Meanwhile this was asked on MO and has an accepted answer: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/110739/